# Async/Await variable affectation in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I would like to achieve the following thing in JS but I've got the feeling that I don't have the right approach.

- I'm doing a first request giving me a list of objects
- For each object I'm doing another request to an API to get matching values
- Apply a specific logic to the result
- Finally call a function that uses the data provided by the API and modified

My code looks like this :

```
async function processData(){
    const models = await fetch('/api/models').then(response => response.json());
    for(let m in models){
        for(let i of models[m].items){
            if(i.type == 1){
                i.values = await fetch('/api/main/'+i.id).then(response => response.json());
            }
            else{
                i.values = await fetch('/api/custom/'+i.id).then(response => response.json());
                // + additionnal specific code on values
            }
            console.log(i.values);//<--- NOT WHAT EXPECTED
        }
        display(models[m]);
    }
}
```

My problem is that `display` function is called before `i.values` is updated.
I think the whole `for(let i models[m].items){}` loop should be asynchronous and the `display` function should be called only once all `fetch` requests for each `i` item have been resolved.
But I'm struggling to write the code and I'm not sure this is the good way of doing this.

Comment: You do `for(let m in models){` which iterates over the *keys* as `m` thus `models[m].items` is the correct way to get the value for that key. However, `'/api/main/'+m.id` does not make sense, as the key is supposed to be a string and strings don't have an `id` property. Is that supposed to be `i.id`?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I changed some variable names to make my code easier before pasting it here, and made some mistakes while doing it. I'm editing the post! Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: Well, [I tried to reproduce the issue](https://jsbin.com/navuvon/1/edit?js,console) by mocking out the `fetch` calls and I noticed it was calling `/api/main/undefined`. If you change to `i.id`, then the code seems to work. I don't see the behaviour you describe - `value` is updated properly before being displayed.